# Decode Base64 encoded data on the java server

Tags: java, android, base64

**Approach:** I am encoding simple data to base64 and then sending it to the server. Similarly, i am trying to decode base64 encoded data on Java server but there is always exception that it is unable to decode it properly. Any help is appreciated.

Client Code Snippet(Android Application):

```
private String random(int size) {

  Random generator = new Random();
  StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  //int randomLength = generator.nextInt(size);
  char tempChar;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(90 - 65) + 65);
      randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
  }
  return randomStringBuilder.toString();
}


String data = random(packetSize);
Log.d(data, " Random String");

byte [] encodedBuffer = Base64.encode(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0);
DatagramPacket packet =
        new DatagramPacket(encodedBuffer, encodedBuffer.length, address, dstPort);
Log.d(String.valueOf(packetSize), "Sending packet Size");

SocketHandler.getSocket().send(packet);
```

Server Code Snippet:

```
private String decodeBase64(String encoded) {
  try
  {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String decodeData = new String(decodedBytes);
    return decodeData;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to decode");
    return null;
  }
}

public void run() {
  try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1400];
    DatagramPacket packet = packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    System.out.println("UDP Server waiting");
    while(true)
    {

      try {
        SocketHandler.getSocket().receive(packet);
        System.out.println("Received: " + decodeBase64(new String(packet.getData())));

      }
      catch (SocketException e1) {
        System.out.println("Socket closed " + e1);
      }
    }
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 147
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:742)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
```

**Sample Input(Random String generated):**

LVYAGHNVAUUEVNSEQHLHNNHGOHKFJQICSGXMXLJGBICOGJTWGBFLRSROJQWIWCETRXMTDWASGILXCDPRBIYAWFTBRRWN

Comment: Provide sample data, original, after Base64 encoding, received by the server, decoded by the server. If the data is binary provide it in hex.

Comment: Also add the Exception thrown

Comment: The "Run code snippet" stuff is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` for decoding instead of Base64. For me it helps.
For example replace:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

with

```
byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64str)
```

Comment: It works but the problem is that now it gives more characters. For example my input was FMKPARSQQTIENUDYWMRWXKGEEAOHFJBEXMKGWCUFBPICEGYNXEQWQDDOXWORLVGNHNLALVUEWVXLHUKAMRHSPONMAMRB and when i decode it, it becomes FMKPARSQQTIENUDYWMRWXKGEEAOHFJBEXMKGWCUFBPICEGYNXEQWQDDOXWORLVGNHNLALVUEWVXLHUKAMRHSPONMAMRBHLBTQNEDTOOMDQERNFDEQGLDOBCVQQBCNQIGPYPSBNNSAIJGQIDASRPPIBIDXUJUXY. More characters are added which were not part of the original string. Any idea why ?

Comment: Try to use DatatypeConverter for encoding too (or some other implementation of Base64 decoding/encoding) and compare strings. For me the problem was that converted to base64 data was too big and `Base64` class cut my data.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this

```
import java.util.Base64;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = new String("FMKPARSQQTIENUDYWMRWXKGEEAOHFJBEXMKGWCUFBPICEGYNXEQWQDDOXWOR‌LVGNHNLALVUEWVXLHUKA‌MRHSPONMAMRB");
    System.out.println("input " + input);
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(input.getBytes());
    System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBytes);
    System.out.println("output " + new String(decodedBytes));

 }
```

Compiled and executed online it gives

input FMKPARSQQTIENUDYWMRWXKGEEAOHFJBEXMKGWCUFBPICEGYNXEQWQDDOXWORâLVGNHNLALVUEWVXLHUKAâMRHSPONMAMRB

encodedBytes Rk1LUEFSU1FRVElFTlVEWVdNUldYS0dFRUFPSEZKQkVYTUtHV0NVRkJQSUNFR1lOWEVRV1FERE9YV09Sw6LCgMKMTFZHTkhOTEFMVlVFV1ZYTEhVS0HDosKAwoxNUkhTUE9OTUFNUkI=

output 
FMKPARSQQTIENUDYWMRWXKGEEAOHFJBEXMKGWCUFBPICEGYNXEQWQDDOXWORâLVGNHNLALVUEWVXLHUKAâMRHSPONMAMRB